# NDB - querying repeated structured property for attribute

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine

I have two models:

```
class Author(ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=true)

class Course(ndb.Model):
    student = ndb.StructuredProperty(Author, repeated=True)
```

I am trying to query Course to find where a student's email matches that of user.email_address. Is it possible to structure this as a single query?

Answer (score 2):

You have to query by using Author object as a filter

```
query = Course.query(Course.student.email == 'my@email.com')
```

But this query is correct only if you are querying for a single property. Official documentation suggests to use following filter

```
query = Course.query(Course.student == Student(email='my@email.com'))
```

See https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/queries#filtering_structured_properties for more information

Comment: You are also querying a Structured property, make sure to add the index to the index.yaml if not auto generated